# email RenderLog with nice formatting

Tags: python, email, maya

So I'm writing a script in python that dumps a renderlog to a text file and then emails it to the user inside the body of the message.

I'm using the python read like so:

```
f=open('filename.txt','r')
f.read()
```

where `f` is the file instance. The output I get is not very user readable.

> '# \'// Warning: Render view: Selected region is too small // \r\ndefaultPointLight(1, 1,1,1, 0, 0, 0,0,0, 1);\r\nrenderWindowRender redoPreviousRender renderView;\r\n

when I'd much rather have it display like

> // Warning: Render view: Selected region is too small //
>
> defaultPointLight(1, 1,1,1, 0, 0, 0,0,0, 1);
>
> renderWindowRender redoPreviousRender renderView;

Is there a simple way to convert the \r and \n to linebreaks in the email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a very quick-and-dirty way, you can use .replace(r'\r\n', '\n'), eg:

```
>>> print '# \'// Warning: Render view: Selected region is too small // \r\ndefaultPointLight(1, 1,1,1, 0, 0, 0,0,0, 1);\r\nrenderWindowRender redoPreviousRender renderView;\r\n'.replace(r'\r\n', '\n')
# '// Warning: Render view: Selected region is too small // 
defaultPointLight(1, 1,1,1, 0, 0, 0,0,0, 1);
renderWindowRender redoPreviousRender renderView;
```

The "r" in the r'\r\n' means, that the string should be understood literally contrary to the '\n', which is the actual linebreak.

(Actually, I don't know what is your platform's linebreak character. Change '\n' accordingly)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to send your email in HTML format. By doing this you are able to format it with various HTML tags.
Then simply replace break characters with `<br/>` tag.

```
log.replace('\n','<br/>').replace('\n\r','<br/>')
```

[Here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/802315/) is a good mailing code with html support.